# Excel Copy Cell

Tags: excel, copy, cell

Example below: As you cansee the FBR00001 s/w beef bacon i just do the manual paste but the others i wanto to copy in easy way in one time not in manual.. can anyone please answer this below as i really need to learn this tricks.. many thanks

```
Position    Type
FBR00001    S/W BEEF BACON
FBR00001    S/W BEEF BACON
FBR00001    S/W BEEF BACON
FBR00001    S/W BEEF BACON
FBR00001    S/W BEEF BACON
FBR00001    S/W BEEF BACON
FBR00001    S/W BEEF BACON

FBR00006    S/W BEEF PASTRAMI OATMEAL PANINI
    Item
    Item
    Item
    Item
    Item
    Item

FBR00007    S/W BEEF ROAST
    Item
    Item
    Item
    Item
    Item
    Item
    Item

FBR00009    dl S/W BEEF ROAST CIABATTA BREAD
    Item
    Item
    Item
    Item
    Item
    Item

FBR00010    dl S/W BEEF ROAST PANINI BREAD
    Item
    Item
    Item
    Item
    Item
    Item
    Item
```

Answer (score 0):

If I get this correct, you want a quick and easy way to copy the cells down for every item. So your list would look like this:

```
FBR00006    S/W BEEF PASTRAMI OATMEAL PANINI
    Item    S/W BEEF PASTRAMI OATMEAL PANINI
    Item    S/W BEEF PASTRAMI OATMEAL PANINI
    Item    S/W BEEF PASTRAMI OATMEAL PANINI
    Item    S/W BEEF PASTRAMI OATMEAL PANINI
    Item    S/W BEEF PASTRAMI OATMEAL PANINI
    Item    S/W BEEF PASTRAMI OATMEAL PANINI

FBR00007    S/W BEEF ROAST
    Item    S/W BEEF ROAST
    Item    S/W BEEF ROAST
    Item    S/W BEEF ROAST
    Item    S/W BEEF ROAST
    Item    S/W BEEF ROAST
    Item    S/W BEEF ROAST
    Item    S/W BEEF ROAST
```

The easiest way to copy down is to click into the cell you want to copy. Then click and hold the little green dot shown below, in the bottom right corner of a cell. You can drag this down as far as you need and Excel will automatically fill in all of the cells. If you have a list of numbers or dates (1,2,3) this technique will continue the list to (4,5,6,...) as you continue to drag it down. Rather than a manual Ctrl+C / Ctrl+V.

[image: Excel CopyDrag]

Let me know if this is the tip you were looking for, if not please explain your needs a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the column you want to copy and paste is column B

1. Select the Entire Column B
2. Press F5 or Ctrl-G
3. Click "Option"
4. Select "Blank Cell" and Confirm
5. put the equal sign and the upper cell address like this

[image: Or you can just write the equal sign and use the up arrow]

Or you can just write the equal sign and use the up arrow

6. Ctrl -Enter
7. Copy the Entire Column B and Paste as Value.

At this you have some rows which have items in Column B but is blank in Column A

To Clear Contents in Column B of these row, do the follow steps.

8. Apply AutoFilter
9. Filter in Column A to show only blank cells
10. delete all the rows except the first row(the title row)